# selenium get li element based on index position and click the checkbox

Tags: java, selenium

I have this HTML now using Selenium I ant to toggle the li element with given index position say 1, where it indicates I want to click the toggle checkbox for spring.

```
<ul id="todo-list" data-woven="abc">
<li class="active" data-index="0">
    <div class="view">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
        <label>Java</label>
        <button class="destroy"></button>
    </div>
    <input class="edit">
</li>
<li class="active" data-index="1">
    <div class="view">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
        <label>Spring</label>
        <button class="destroy"></button>
    </div>
    <input class="edit">
</li></ul>
```

I am completely new to selenium so not able to understand how can we achieve this.

I know to get the `UL` elements using the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("todo-list"));
```

Now how can get the `li` element based on its `index` and `click` the corresponding `checkbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the *checkbox* element with respect to the ancestor `<li>` nodes **index** attribute you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#todo-list li.active[data-index='1'] input")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='todo-list']//li[@class='active' and @data-index='1']//input")).click();
  ```

Comment: Now I have another small question, once I get the specific `li` element, if I want to click the button inside it with class `destroy`, how to do that? I used the xpath approach to access button after li but I am getting errors.

Comment: @learner Replace `input` with `button`, effectively `ul#todo-list li.active[data-index='1'] button`

Comment: Can we do it with xpath also same process?

Comment: @learner Effective xpath: `//ul[@id='todo-list']//li[@class='active' and @data-index='1']//button`

Comment: I am getting error as `element not interactable exception` for this button operation

Comment: Following sbling with xpath might help. `//ul[@id='todo-list']//li[@class='active' and @data-index='1']//input/following-sbling::button`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xpath` to locate an element with `data-index=1`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-index='1']//input[@class='toggle']"));
```

Or with `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-index='1'] .toggle"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot compare based on text spring here, I just want to pick an element based on index, I just gave spring as example. Can you please tell me the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Next I want to click the toggle checkbox for it, how to do that, can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You could find the element you are looking for directly with the answer @Guy gave you and that would be the right way if you knew exactly what the data-index attribute would be set to, but you could also find a collection of the li elements and then proceed to do what you need within each like this:

```
var container = driver.findElement(By.id("todo-list"));

var elements = container.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

with elements you can loop through each or go directly to the one you want.